# Chirp Running on Maemo

Tags: python, debian, maemo, n900

I'm trying to get Chirp to run under Maemo5 (a debian based mobile operating system).

When running .chirpw or setup.py I get this as a result

```
Nokia-N900:~/compile/chirp-0.3.1# ./chirpw
CHIRP 0.3.1 on Linux - Maemo 5 %h (Python 2.5.4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./chirpw", line 105, in <module>
    from chirp import *
  File "/root/compile/chirp-0.3.1/chirp/icq7.py", line 50
    class ICQ7Radio(icf.IcomCloneModeRadio):
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using the chirp source found here: http://chirp.danplanet.com/download/0.3.1/chirp-0.3.1.tar.gz

The idea is to be able to program my radios from my linux powered phone, however I can't seem to figure out why the program is getting held up on the ICQ7Radio class.

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That version is quite old, have a try with latest daily build http://trac.chirp.danplanet.com/chirp_daily/LATEST/

You can also download full hg repository with

```
hg clone http://d-rats.com/hg/chirp.hg
```

See also http://chirp.danplanet.com/projects/chirp/wiki/Developers